# Strange Python strip() behavior

Tags: python, string, strip

I don't understand why the strip() function returns the way it does below. I want to strip() the last occurence of Axyx. I got around it by using rstrip('Axyx') but what's the explanation for the following?

```
>>>"Abcd Efgh Axyx".strip('Axyx')
'bcd Efgh '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string passed to `strip` is treated as a bunch of characters, not a string. Thus, `strip('Axyx')` means "strip occurrences of `A`, `x`, or `y` from either end of the string".

If you actually want to strip a prefix or suffix, you'd have to write that logic yourself. For example:

```
s = 'Abcd Efgh Axyx'
if s.endswith('Axyx'):
    s = s[:-len('Axyx')]
```

Comment: Is there a compact way to delete the first occurence of a substring from the right from a string?

Comment: Is the 'Axyx' that you want to delete always at the very end of the string, or is there sometimes material in between 'Axyx' and the end?

Comment: From re module Use re.sub()

Comment: Its always at the end but there might be a space after it

Comment: @user3079275 See edit

Comment: The answer here works if you also check for the space. An alternative is to use `re.sub()` to substitute a string for a regular expression match. If your string is `s`, then you'd do: `s = re.sub('Axyx ?$', '', s)`

Comment: I had to do x = x[:-(1+len('Axyx'))].strip() and it works. Its len() + 1

Answer (score 0):

Because strip() returns a copy of the string that you provided without the characters that you gave as input. 
For example:
"12345".strip('123') returns: '45'. 
So, strip() does not remove words or something but removes all the characters that the string that you give as input has, both from the end and the beginning of the string that you want to strip.